# Devise rails 4 - Can't edit my new.html.erb file under devise registration

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

i'm new to rails so any help would be much appreciated.

- i am using 'rails', '4.2.0'
- i have installed the gem 'devise', '~> 3.4.0'
- i have followed the step as per documentation `gem 'devise'` | `rails generate devise:install` | `rails generate devise User` | `rails generate devise:views users`
- i am trying to edit my signup form located in users/registrations/new.html.erb
- i am trying to edit my sign up form to add more fields and css it
- but when i edit my registration new.html.erb the new additional changes do not
  display via http://localhost:3000/users/sign_up
- even when i delete all the contents in the new.html.erb file, the
  http://localhost:3000/users/sign_up still displays an emaill and
  password field with all contents delete from the new.html.erb file

> What i want to do, is to be able to edit my signup form page by adding
>   html text contents, ids & classes to be able to style the page - but when i edit my new.html.erb devise registration page no new changes appear in the display via http://localhost:3000/users/sign_up - can one kindly advise me how i edit my signup page

i am unsure where i am going wrong and any help will be much appreciated

rake routes:

```
 Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                    Controller#Action
        new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)       devise/sessions#new
            user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)       devise/sessions#create
    destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)      devise/sessions#destroy
           user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#create
       new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)  devise/passwords#new
      edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format) devise/passwords#edit
                         PATCH  /users/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#update
                         PUT    /users/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#update
cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)        devise/registrations#cancel
       user_registration POST   /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#create
   new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)       devise/registrations#new
  edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)          devise/registrations#edit
                         PATCH  /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#update
                         PUT    /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#update
                         DELETE /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#destroy
                   users GET    /users(.:format)               users#index
                         POST   /users(.:format)               users#create
                new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)           users#new
               edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)      users#edit
                    user GET    /users/:id(.:format)           users#show
                         PATCH  /users/:id(.:format)           users#update
                         PUT    /users/:id(.:format)           users#update
                         DELETE /users/:id(.:format)           users#destroy
                    root GET    /                              static_pages#landingpg
```

views/users/registrations/new.html

> i have placed (Appear Here) on the first line but still nothing
>   changes via http://localhost:3000/users/sign_up as per the image

```
<h2>Sign up (Appear Here)</h2>

<%= simple_form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

  <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.input :email, required: true, autofocus: true %>
    <%= f.input :password, required: true, hint: ("#{@minimum_password_length} characters minimum" if @validatable) %>
    <%= f.input :password_confirmation, required: true %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit, "Sign up" %>
  </div>
<% end %>

<%= render "users/shared/links" %>
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Did you save the changes?

Comment: yes i did save changes

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You've used generator to generate scoped views:

```
rails generate devise:views users
```

Have you set `config.scoped_views = true` inside the `config/initializers/devise.rb` file ?

After doing so, you will be able to have views based on the role like `users/registrations/new` and `admins/registrations/new`.

Comment: thank you!! i forgot to set the `config.scoped_views = true`